# get the value from input kendo ComboBox using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

I am using kendo comboBox in my app and I need to get value and ID of record out of ComboBox, outside the ComboBox actual function.... I am using comboBox dropdown in table against each record so I can't relay on css ID to get comboBox value... I have managed to reach to input comboBox of selected record and I did this test by apply background color to it. I have tested .val() which works fine for just input textbox but its not happening for kendo ComboBox...

Many Thanks

### input

```
  <td class="N_td">@Html.TextBox("Input_MarkingSchemeTitle_Element", null, new { id = @item.ElementID + "_EMST", @class = "ElementMarkingSchemeTitle k1-grid-input k-textbox_3 _MarkSchemeId_Input" })  </td>
```

### ComboBox function

```
 $("._MarkSchemeId_Input").kendoComboBox({
        minLength: 1,
        filter: 'contains',
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: false,
            transport: {
                read: "/Qualification/GetAllMarkScheme_JSON"
            },
        },
        change: function () {

           alert("value " + this.value() + "   " + this.text());                      
        }
    });
```

### jQuery function

```
$("#ElementTable").on("click", ".k1-grid-confirm", function () {


   $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input").css("background", "red");

   var a1 = $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input").text(); // doesn't work

        alert("a1  " + a1);
 .....
```

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the Kendo [demo](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/web/combobox/index.html), it actually shows precisely what are you interested in

```
 var fabric = $("#fabric").data("kendoComboBox");
                var select = $("#size").data("kendoComboBox");
                $("#get").click(function() {
                    alert('Thank you! Your Choice is:\n\nFabric ID: ' +   fabric.value() + ' and Size: ' + select.value());
                });
```

The value retrieval in your example is not working because you are calling method at the html element not a Kendo control. Consider this [example](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/web/combobox#methods-value) :

```
$("#combobox").kendoComboBox({
  dataSource: [ "Apples", "Oranges" ]
});
var combobox = $("#combobox").data("kendoComboBox");
combobox.value("Oranges");
```

Therefore in your case do following :

```
$(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input").data("kendoComboBox").text()
```

Comment: I have use data.kendo and use value() with it to get text but my alert is not even call.... as I have mension I am using class with kendo ComboBox as I have multiple instance of it in table ... here is my code...                 var ComboData = $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input").data("kendoComboBox");

alert(">>>  " + ComboData.value());

Comment: Place a debugger into your on click method and see what does the selector brings you back in the console. By the sound of it you are not assigning the event correctly or js error before the alert. find() can return more then one element in that case you use indexer to select specific one.  `$(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input")[0]`

Comment: I have tried following line and css only applies to only selected comboxBox input, which means this is finding write input!! correct??   $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input").css("background", "red");

Comment: First try to replicate what is shown in the kendo demo and start from there - you can edit their example so its good starting point. If your combobox looks like combobox you are not missing anything. Focus at the selector as your event is not firing!

Comment: ok I have found the issue, if I use <input class="._MarkSchemeId_Input" then it doesn't work but it does work with id="._MarkSchemeId_Input" NOW my issue is I have multiple instances of kendo ComboBox...

Comment: i have answer my question as above

Comment: sorry what do you mean ? hope I was any help and your combobox is now working as expected ?

Comment: no I mean good way... your guidance was very helpful and it lead me to my answer ... many thanks

Answer (score 2):

By design, the ComboBox widget copies all styles and CSS classes from the original element to the visible input. This is documented [here](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/getting-started/web/combobox/overview). If you examine the rendered HTML it will look like this:

- original element + initialization code

```
    <input class="custom-class" />
    <script>
        $(function() {
            $(".custom-class").kendoComboBox();
        });
    </script>
```

- results in this HTML

```
    <span class="k-widget k-combobox k-header custom-class">
      <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-dropdown-wrap k-state-default">
        <input class="k-input custom-class" type="text" autocomplete="off" style="width: 100%;">
        <span tabindex="-1" unselectable="on" class="k-select">
          <span unselectable="on" class="k-icon k-i-arrow-s" role="button" tabindex="-1">
            select
          </span>
        </span>
      </span>
      <input class="custom-class" data-role="combobox" style="display: none;">
    </span>
```

As you can see the **custom-class** is copied to wrapper element and to the visible input. Because of this you will need to use a more specific selector to find only the original input elements:

```
$(".custom-class[data-role=combobox]");
```

Note that this will return a list of input elements. If you need to get selected data items, you will need to loop them and get the combobox instance for each of the input element.

[Here](http://jsbin.com/zufoxena/2/edit) I prepared a simple jsBin demo, which shows how to accomplish this.

Comment: my requirement is get only selected 1 on click event and i have managed to reach that using jQuery $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkSchemeId_Input").css("background", "red");

Answer (score 1):

I have managed to resolve the issue as following

```
<td class="N_td">@Html.TextBox("Input_MarkingSchemeTitle_Element", null, new { id = @item.ElementID + "_EMST", @class = "ElementMarkingSchemeTitle k1-grid-input k-textbox_3 _MarkScheme_Input" })  </td>


 //--get all the MarkScheme from database and put in drop-down 
    $("._MarkScheme_Input").kendoComboBox({
        minLength: 1,
        filter: 'contains',
        dataTextField: "Name",
        dataValueField: "ID",
        dataSource: {
            type: "json",
            serverFiltering: false,
            transport: {
                read: "/Qualification/GetAllMarkScheme_JSON"
            },
        },
        change: function () {

           // alert("value " + this.value() + "   " + this.text());                      //if it need to test selected record data...    
      }
    });


 $("#ElementTable").on("click", ".k1-grid-confirm", function () {


        $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkScheme_Input").css("background", "red");

        //read all the input 'comboxBox' in loop...
        //var _comboBoxInput = $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkScheme_Input").filter("[data-role=combobox]");
        //_comboBoxInput.each(function (idx, input) {
        //    alert("idx " + idx + "  \n input " + input);
        //    var combobox = $(input).data("kendoComboBox");
        //    alert("ID>>>  : " + combobox.value() + ", Text: >>> " + combobox.text());
        //});

        //-------------------------
        var input = $(this).closest('table').find("._MarkScheme_Input");
        var comboboxInput = input.filter("[data-role=combobox]");
        var combobox = comboboxInput.data("kendoComboBox");
        var selectedText = combobox.text();
        var selectedValue = combobox.value();
        var dataItem = combobox.dataItem();

        alert("ID>>>  : " + selectedValue + ", Text: >>> " + selectedText);
```